# Gravitational attraction calculation

Tags: javascript, node.js, trigonometry

I am trying to do a simple 2d gravitational attraction problem where each player controls a particle. The math seems to make sense before I try to modify the speed of the particle. As soon as I move the particle and the angle becomes non 0, the particles move quickly to 0,0 and then all the values become NaN. Any Ideas on why this happens?

```
for(var i in Player.list){  
        var player = Player.list[i];
        if(player.id !== self.id){
            var xDisp = self.x - player.x;
            var yDisp = self.y - player.y;
            var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDisp, 2) + Math.pow(yDisp, 2));
            var angle = Math.atan2(yDisp, xDisp);
            console.log("angle:" + angle);
            if(distance !== 0){
                attractionAcceleration = GRAVITATIONAL_ATTRACTION_CONSTANT / Math.pow(distance^2); //add mass calculation later when mass is variable
                self.spdX += attractionAcceleration * Math.cos(angle);
                console.log("self.spdX :" + self.spdX);
                self.spdY -= attractionAcceleration * Math.sin(angle);  
                console.log("self.spdy:" + self.spdY);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add `Player`.

Comment: In programming languages, annoyingly, `^` means XOR, not to-the-power-of. So say for example distance is 12. 12^2 = 1100^0010 = 1110 = 14. So `Math.pow(12^2)` = `Math.pow(12^2, undefined)` = `Math.pow(14, undefined)` and 14 raised to the power of `undefined` is not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `Math.pow(distance^2)` which should be `Math.pow(distance,2)`. That explains why the result became NaN.

Comment: Should explain that the `^` means XOR